# Update to Django 1.7 with pip

Tags: python, django, django-1.5, django-1.7

I updated from Django 1.5.8 to 1.7:

```
pip install Django==1.7
Downloading/unpacking Django==1.7
  Downloading Django-1.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.4MB): 7.4MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: Django
  Found existing installation: Django 1.5.8
    Uninstalling Django:
      Successfully uninstalled Django
  Rolling back uninstall of Django
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1435, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 671, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 901, in move_wheel_files
    pycompile=self.pycompile,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 247, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, dest, False, fixer=fixer, filter=filter)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 209, in clobber
    shutil.copy2(srcfile, destfile)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 130, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py'

Storing debug log for failure in /Users/stefanieness/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

This is my error message.

But when I run

```
python
import django
print(django.get_version())
```

I get 1.7. Can I use the version like that or do I have to reinstall it? Will it work?

Thank you!

Comment: Permission error means you dont have permission. Please try once `pip install "Django==1.7"` as `root` user.

Comment: Consider using a virtualenv, and install django 1.7 there. That way you wont run into issues with permissioning, etc..

Comment: I'm getting the same problem doing a clean installation of 1.7, using virtualenv. Part of the whole point of virtualenv is that I shouldn't need root. Unfortunately, it seems that an installation script for a client project is what sudo-installed Django for me in the first place. I wish I'd scrutinised their script before running it with sudo. :-(

Answer (score 4):

This is because the first time you installed django, you did `sudo pip install django`, which has installed django in your global Python interpreter as the root user (or the superuser).

You can only have one version of django in your global Python interpreter, so once you upgrade it, any of your django applications that are using the global Python interpreter (in other words, not using a virtual environment) will be automatically upgraded to 1.7

If you don't have any other django projects, then this doesn't really have any negative effects - but as a best practice, you should use [virtual environments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) so that you can easily test versions of libraries.

To solve your immediate problem, you need to `sudo pip install -U django` which will upgrade django to the latest stable release.